# spark dataframe not dropping columns after df.drop() operation

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I'm using jupyter notebook and running spark 2.4.3.

```
game_reviews = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("./amazon_reviews_us_Video_Games_v1_00.tsv")
#reading is fine

game_reviews_2_columns =game_reviews.drop(
'marketplace','review_id','product_parent','product_title','product_category',
                       'helpful_votes' ,'total_votes','vine','verified_purchase','review_headline',
                       'review_body','review_date')
```

running this code

```
game_reviews_2_columns.columns
```

still gives all columns:

> ['marketplace\tcustomer_id\treview_id\tproduct_id\tproduct_parent\tproduct_title\tproduct_category\tstar_rating\thelpful_votes\ttotal_votes\tvine\tverified_purchase\treview_headline\treview_body\treview_date']

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your `game_reviews`? It looks like there is only one column with a so long name. I guess you should use `delimiter="\t"` in your read operation.

Comment: @Sraw, yes there is '\t operation, does it affect?

Comment: @Sraw, damn it read the whole column as 1 string, it did not read it right way

Comment: Well, a CSV file is basically a normal text file with delimiter and line breaker. Normally, the delimiter is `,` and the line breaker is `\n`. So that's the default option. But in your case, I believe your delimiter is not `,` but `\t`. That's why you need to specify delimiter. Or spark will treat the whole line as one column.

Comment: damn, it works after included 'option("delimiter", "\t")'

Answer (score 0):

It did not read properly the headers, it was a list of one huge string of columns and tabs.

```
game_reviews = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").
    option("delimiter","\t"). #this is the parameter

load("./amazon_reviews_us_Video_Games_v1_00.tsv")
```

I could specify schema and include it too, but it works fine.